# What's causing folder to change ownership?

Tags: permissions, directory

I have something funky going on with a few folders I'm hosting on a parallel filesystem. Every so often, the group ownership on the folders will revert to

```
root:root
```

Instead of an appropriate service group, eg:

```
root:authorized_group
```

Is there a way I can backtrack or log which process and parents process are affiliated with the group change on the folder?

Comment: Is the inode of the directory also changing?  If so that would indicate that the ownership is not being _changed_; the entire _directory_ is being removed and replaced.  You might be able to use `inotify` to at least pin down _when_ the change is being made, if not by _what_.

Comment: I'm not sure about the inode change. I'd assume not, as the group change is pretty seamless. In order for the inode to change the folder would have to be copied to a new location, correct? Seems unlikely as the folder holds about 100TB of data.

Comment: Why assume and trust when you could `ls -i` to probe and verify?

Comment: It would take nearly 4 days to write that much data to disk in our current setup. I mean it wasn't a bad idea, it was just only applicable for a smaller scale of storage. Found the issue though, was chown-ing a symbolic link. Sometimes I feel like a nut... sometimes I dont. :D

Comment: Maybe I could use something like rsyslog or auditd in the future to track this stuff down? As I believe one or the other can capture all commands, and associated file changes (including ownership)